# Slow Firestore Queries in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very simple query which is quite slow (5seconds or more) when running it on my android.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await userTeamPointsCollection
        .where('user_ref', isEqualTo: userIdRef)
        .where('season_id', isEqualTo: season)
        .where('match_day', isEqualTo: matchday)
        .get();
```

The collection consists of 10 documents, so i have no idea why the query might be slow.
I have already created a composite index, there was not much improvement.

DO you have any suggestions on what i should try or why it is so slow? (Internet is not an issue...)

Best regards,

Comment: What happens if you set the offline persistence off? 
`FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);` Complex queries may be slow with offline persistence because they don't take advantages of the index stored in the backend.

Comment: Hi!

This seemed to have solved the issue. However, i don't want to abandon offline persistence entirely => is it possible to turn it off only for *some* queries?

Comment: No, it is global for the Firestore DB.

Comment: Ok thank you. That's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for fast synchronization of (frequent) relatively small write operations, consider using Firebase's Realtime Database over Cloud Firestore.

Firebase has two NoSQL databases: Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database. Both database's offer real-time synchronization as one of their core primitives, but Realtime Database is often faster and handles small write operations more efficiently (and often cheaper), while Firestore is best if you have relatively big documents, a larger number of (50K-1M concurrent) listeners, and relatively fewer write operations.

For more info please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004347/sending-data-to-firestore-is-slow)